# ReferenceError: "$" is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Getting error ReferenceError: "$" is not defined.  when below function is run. I have enabled Sheets API in both Google API console & Advanced Google Services

```
function createTriggers2() {
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>;

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://api.msg91.com/api/v2/sendsms",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "authkey": "My_auth_key",
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{ \"sender\": \"SOCKET\", \"route\": \"4\", \"country\": \"91\", \"sms\": [ { \"message\": \"Message1\", \"to\": [ \"96xxxxx\", \"70xxxxx\" ] }, { \"message\": \"Message2\", \"to\": [ \"98260XXXXX\", \"98261XXXXX\" ] } ] }"
};


$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
}
```

Comment: Is the `createTriggers2()` function in a **gs** script file?  If so, you can't put a `<script>` tag in server side code.  You can't put a `<script>` tag inside of a function anyway.

Comment: Please checkout [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not being loaded because you have an HTML tag in your javascript.  Move this line out into the HTML, above where you call jQuery:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>;
```

Comment: I have not created any HTML in the project. I created only code.gs in the project & above is the excerpt from it.

Should we create HTML as well?

Comment: Yes, you will need to parse your `script` tag as HTML.